# How to select content of HTML attribute with single shortcut press in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find out how to select the whole content of HTML attribute. For example I have a div with class

```
<div class="menu-link font-size-bigger font-weight-bold"></div>
```

So now when I want to select all classes "menu-link font-size-bigger font-weight-bold" I must press smartSelect.grow 3x

Is there a better way. I just want to use one shortcut press. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case you need to install an extension. You could try these:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chunsen.bracket-select
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StAlYo.select-quotes